# How to adjust webp quality settings in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, webp

I am trying to introduce webp images to a TYPO3 V10 website.

After installing webp on the server and adding webp to `$GLOBALS[‘TYPO3_CONF_VARS’][‘GFX’][‘imagefile_ext’]` I am able to use it both in fluid and typoscript.
But the results are not as good as expected. Some images are smaller, some are bigger, overall there is no improvement.

I have set the jpeg quality to 75 in `$GLOBALS[‘TYPO3_CONF_VARS’][‘GFX’][‘jpg_quality’]`.

Is there a way to adjust the webp quality as well?

I am not using the webp extension.

Comment: After debugging a bit around `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\CommandUtility::imageMagickCommand()` I don't think this is currently possible. `jpg_quality` does not affect the ImageMagick command used to generate webp. I am sure it would be a well-received Feature Request at https://forge.typo3.org. Would you add one?

Comment: I added a feature request, it is my first one, any comments?
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/96925

Comment: That looks great. Thanks.